# how to update getIntent() when called another application

Tags: android

I want to passing parameter by intent from 2 more another applications.
but `getIntent()` includes always same values in `onResume()`.
see codes. at the blow

**app1("com.mycompany.app1")**

```
Intent appLaunchIntent = activity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mycompany.destinationapp");
appLaunchIntent.putExtra("token", "123456789");
activity.startActivity(appLaunchIntent);
```

**app2("com.mycompany.app2")**

```
Intent appLaunchIntent = activity.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.mycompany.destinationapp");
appLaunchIntent.putExtra("token", "abcdefghi");
activity.startActivity(appLaunchIntent);
```

**destination apps("com.mycompany.destinationapp")**

```
@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
     final Intent intent = getIntent();
     if (intent.hasExtra("token")) {
            receivedToken = intent.getStringExtra("token"); //123456789

    //**** always same value from *app2 

    //**** how to update getIntent() or other way?

     }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your activity does not use any attributes from manifest such as `android:launchMode="singleTop"` or `android:launchMode="singleTask"` then sending another intent to start an activity should use the new intent you sent and open a different activity. However if you do use something like that, then while the activity is open, `onNewIntent(Intent intent)` method will be called. You can update the intent with the following code to use new values.

```
@Override
public void onNewIntent(Intent intent){
    setIntent(intent);
}
```

This is basically what you need to do to update the value at `getIntent()` and nothing else.

Comment: I modify activity to android:launchMode="singleTop" in manifest. 
so, onNewIntent() was called. 
thanks @Furkan Yurdakul

Comment: @KangDeveloper no problem, I'm glad that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `getIntent` inside `onResume`.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (intent.hasExtra("token")) {
        receivedToken = intent.getStringExtra("token");
    }
}
```

Comment: yes I know but getIntent() is always same when called onResume.

Comment: I called destApp by app1. and press home button. I called destApp by app2. then, getIntent() value on onResume is same. always, getting "123456789"

Comment: appreciate of your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to define intent filter on sender activity 

<activity android:name="ShareActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>


In Reciever application Activity you have to manage like below 
Intent intent = getIntent();
    Uri data = intent.getData();

    // Figure out what to do based on the intent type
    if (intent.getType().indexOf("image/") != -1) {
        // Handle intents with image data ...
    } else if (intent.getType().equals("text/plain")) {
        // Handle intents with text ...
    }
```